# Привести строки массива к числу JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, map

Есть массив `var myMass = ["20", null, undefined, "5", {}, 700];`.
Нужно привести все значения к числу. Вот что получилось у меня - приводятся к числу, если значение либо строка, либо число.

Как быть с остальными типами?

```
var result  = myMass.map(function(num, index, arr) {
if ((typeof myMass[index] == 'number' || 'string')) {
return parseInt(myMass[index]);
} else ????
});
```

Comment: ну а если элемент массива не может быть преобразован в число, что должно произойти?

Comment: другие элементы должны остаться как есть!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверяйте результат конвертации:

```js
var myMass = ["20", null, undefined, "5", {}, 700];

var result  = myMass.map(function(item, index, arr) {
  var number = parseInt(item);
  return isNaN(number)? item : number;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!!!!

Comment: @ЕленаЛещенко На здоровье. Слева галочка - щёлк :). Успехов!

Comment: Было: var number = parseInt(item); // "43алалалала" => 43; "43" => 43
Стало: var number = Number(item); // "43алалалал" => null; "43" => 43
Или короче: var number = +item; //Аналогично предыдущему

Comment: Короче, замени var number = parseInt(item); на var number = +item;

Comment: PROPHESSOR, не подходит под условие задачи - если меняю на +item -  мне null преобразовывает в 0. А мне нужно, чтобы оно осталось, как null. Но все равно спасибо!